# How to determine the interval for the domain of an inverse function of a quadratic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, inverse

**Question**

How to determine the interval for the domain of an inverse function of a quadratic function

For an example the graph of $y=x^2$ 's inverse has the domain of x is larger or equal to 0 using algebraic methods. (if we were to use graphic it would be obvious)

I was wondering how we determine such interval of the inverse of a quadratic

Answer (score 3):

A function is invertable on an interval for which it is *injective*. A function is injective when $\forall a,b,f(a)=f(b)\Rightarrow a=b$ (think about why this would guarantee an inverse!).

It's not too hard to show that a quadratic equation is injective on an interval if and only if the interval is entirely on one side of its local min/max. The $x$ coordinate of the min/max is given by $x=\frac{-b}{2a}$, so the quadratic is invertable on the intervals $(-\infty, \frac{-b}{2a}]$ and $[\frac{-b}{2a},\infty)$, as well as any smaller interval that is properly contained in one of those intervals.

The domain of the inverse function is obtained by just applying $f$ to these intervals. That gives $(-\infty, c-\frac{b^2}{4a}]$ and $[c-\frac{b^2}{4a},\infty)$ as the corresponding domains of the inverse function.

Comment: I find these downvotes slightly suspicious...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I guess you probably thought that I downvoted you and Stella's posts in order to put mine to the top. I do not engage in this type of targeted downvoting. Instead, it is because it does not answer this question, which clearly asks for the domain of the inverse function.

Comment: @Displayname You sure about that?  (and not pointing you out at all, I just dislike downvotes without leaving a comment)  IMO, showing the quadratic is not invert-able is a perfectly reasonable approach to the problem

Comment: @Displayname happy now?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt While it is a reasonable approach, your answer makes it sound like the domain of the inverse function would be $[-b/2a,\infty)$ which would confuse the O.P. And everytime I see someone commenting about "suspicious downvotes" I think of an implication of targeted downvoting, sorry I misunderstood you.

Comment: @Displayname I'm sorry, but I'm confused.  I thought **my** answer was pretty clear on the thought that there are two different cases.  And don't worry about the misunderstanding, we should probably just drop it :P

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If we have a quadratic function with image $X$ then the inverses' domain would be $X$.

Example: $f(x) = x^2+100x-271$. Clearly, this function's end behavior is going to infinity, and its lowest point is at its vertex. So its image is $[-2771,\infty)$, as $-2771$ is the y value of its vertex (Verification left to the O. P. as an exercise). As such, the domain of its inverse is $[-2771,\infty)$

Answer (score 1):

A quadratic of the form $y=ax^2+bx+c$ with $a\ne0$, then it has a vertex at $x=-\frac b{2a}$, hence, the domain of the inverse will fall into two cases

---

If $a>0$, then $x\ge-\frac b{2a}$.

---

If $a<0$, then $x\le-\frac b{2a}$